# Under what circumstances would [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame] return null?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to get the dimensions of the main screen, so I use this snippet:

```
NSLog(@"mainScreen frame = %@", [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame]);
```

It's printing

```
mainScreen frame = (null)
```

Earlier it was printing the expected dimensions of my main monitor.

What are some possible causes of this?

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing this. I've had similar results with [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow

Comment: The situation you're running into is probably not the same as what Steve is seeing.  There are documented scenarios in which keyWindow will return nil:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/keyWindow

Are you perhaps hitting the scenario described there: "This method might return nil if the application’s nib file hasn’t finished loading yet or if the receiver is not active." ?

Comment: This is just asking for a "main screen turn on" joke.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the problem here is you're running up against one of the relatively few non-objects in Objective-C Cocoa programming.

The result of "visibleFrame" is an NSRect *structure*, not an object.  To get it to display meaningfully in the NSLog line, you have to do something like this:

```
NSString* frameAsString = NSStringFromRect([[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame]);
NSLog(@"mainScreen frame = %@", frameAsString);
```

There are helper functions for converting many of these structure objects to strings and back, e.g. NSStringFromPoint, NSStringFromRange, etc.

Comment: Ah thanks, I feel pretty silly now I realise what I did. I'm still a beginner at Objective-C.

Comment: It takes a while before all the exceptions to the rules sink in and become second nature. You'll get there!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on this needs to be read carefully.  The "main screen", as Apple defines it, is not necessarily the screen with the menu bar.  The "main screen" is the screen that is receiving keyboard events.  If, for some reason the OS thinks that no screens have the keyboard focus then I could understand why mainScreen would return NULL.

To get the screen with the menu bar (And origin at (0,0)) you need to use:

```
[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0]
```

I've never seen this return NULL, although I won't say that it can't happen.

Comment: It's not even necessarily the one receiving keyboard events. It's the screen with the main window on it. (The window receiving keyboard events is the key window, and may be separate from the main window—for example, it may be a floating panel.)

Comment: I would think that a floating window with the keyboard focus would make that the main screen, even if the main window is on screen 0 from the screens array.

I was just pointing out that the main screen may not be what I had originally assumed it was until I read the docs.  Others may make the same mistake.  My code that made this mistake is burned onto thousands of CDs around the world.

Answer (score 1):

-visibleFrame returns an NSRect struct, while you're using a string specifier for an object. You need to use the NSStringFromRect() function (I believe it's called) to turn the rect into a string object for NSLog().

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to log an object but the method isn't returning an object, it's returning a struct.

Although NSStringFromRect will help you with logging, it's likely you'll want the actual integers elsewhere.

You can accomplish both with:

```
NSLog(@"screen is %.2f wide and %.2f high", [[[NSScreen screens]     
objectAtIndex:0] visibleFrame].size.width,  [[[NSScreen screens] 
objectAtIndex:0] visibleFrame].size.height);
```